# What are the minimal dependencies for an angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

In order to start an angular application from scratch, what are the minimal dependent npm packages are required so that a new developer can start learning from the minimal dependencies.

Comment: hey are you there?

Comment: Yes i am @Aravind .. I have checked your answer.. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the angular official site, the minimal dependencies are  [Workspace npm dependencies](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Following are the minimum dependencies for angular2 application

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",

"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",

"bootstrap": "^3.3.6"  
}
```

In case if you are looking for a much clean start up files you can use my repository from here **[FIRSTANGULAR2APP](https://github.com/aravindfz/firstAngular2App)**

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer could be to use the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new) with `ng new`, which will scaffold a minimal project.